# contentEditable insert br when new line occurs

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

A `contentEditable` has automatic word wrapping, creating a new line when you reach the width of the editable area. This is great but I am parsing the contents of this afterwards and I need it to add a `<br>` when it does this. I have tried everything I can think of and I can't achieve this. Any help greatly received.

Comment: Did you try replacing \n with <br> ?

Comment: "A contentEditable has automatic word wrapping" , any html 'block' element without css 'white-space:nowrap" works like this.

Comment: @Rob - that is true, fairly obvious but also useless information unless it relates somehow to a solution to my problem?

Comment: sorry fella, no suck eggs intended. your questions reads a tad like you didn't know ( by claiming that a contenteditable attribute makes text wrap )

Comment: eg. starting with that as a wrong assumption might be making you think about it the wrong way - what is the top level goal ?

Comment: Its ok, I used a solution from Niels' answer turning off the wrap in the div and making the user hit that enter key - simple but does the job. You get so hung up making your editable div the right width that you dont think of it. I am marking his answer now - thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, the word wrapping point is 'browser discretion' and as such susceptible to font size differences, fonts not being installed, font render engines, anti-aliasing settings etc. etc. The line-wrap point is, so to speak, 'not your problem' from the browser's perspective, and as such it doesn't give this info away.

**Theoretically** you could rebuild the content word-for-word in JS in a dynamically sized and similarly styled div, and monitor for when the height changes - that's where the newlines occur. It'd be a crap load of crappy code to achieve a dodgy result though.

I can't help but feel like you're asking for an [XY-solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here - if you need newlines at the given point, let the end user give them when he wants to. Simply adding `overflow:auto;white-space:nowrap` to the editable element forces them to. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/gmmXu/1/).

Comment: I am thinking maybe on keypress check it is not enter and if the height increased, and insert &lt;br&gt; at the same point - any ideas on achieving that?

Comment: Thanks Niels - I turned off wrapping on the div - make the user hit that enter is the answer. Thanks for making me think outside the box - or rather making my users work inside the box.